# Как красиво передать slice с разными скалярными типами в функцию?

Tags: golang, типы-данных

Есть функция, которая обрезает `slice` со второго элемента и принимает аргумент с типом `[]interface{}`

```
func SliceShift(slice []interface{}) []interface{} {
    if len(slice) > 1 {
        return slice[1:]
    }
    return make([]interface{}, 0)
}
```

Если я попытаюсь передать в аргументе срез строк

```
SliceShift([]string{"a", "b", "c"})
```

то получаю ошибку: `cannot use []string literal (type []string) as type []interface {} in argument to SliceShift`.
Не очень понимаю почему она происходит, но нагулил решение:

```
str := []string{"a", "b", "c"}
newStr := make([]interface{}, len(str))
for i, v := range str {
    newStr[i] = v
}
```

Проблема в том, что мне не хочется каждый раз писать `make([]interface{}, ...)` и цикл копирования.
Можно ли это как-то избежать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*API* довольно странное и будет и далее порождать подобные
проблемы.  Делайте хелпер:

```golang
type any = interface{}

func ss2anys(ss []string) (anys []any) {
    anys = make([]any, len(ss))
    for i := range ss {
        anys[i] = ss[i]
    }

    return anys
}
```

*Playground*:
https://play.golang.org/p/B2xyfjUYYQu.

Answer (score 3):

Из faq по golang

> **Can I convert a []T to an []interface{}?**
>
> Not directly. It is disallowed by the language specification because
>   the two types do not have the same representation in memory. It is
>   necessary to copy the elements individually to the destination slice.
>   This example converts a slice of int to a slice of interface{}:
>
> ```go
> t := []int{1, 2, 3, 4}
> s := make([]interface{}, len(t))
> for i, v := range t {
>    s[i] = v
> }
> ```

Поэтому тут либо функции хелперы под каждый тип, либо так еще можно https://play.golang.org/p/zwqv9ulWW_B

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("String test: %v\n", SliceShift([]string{"a", "b", "c"}))
    fmt.Printf("String test: %v\n", SliceShift([]string{}))
    fmt.Printf("Int test: %v\n", SliceShift([]int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}))

    names := []string{"Igor", "John", "Garry"}
    names = SliceShift(names).([]string)

    fmt.Printf("Names test: %v\n", names)
}

func SliceShift(slice interface{}) interface{} {
    switch v := slice.(type) {
    case []string:
        if len(v) > 1 {
            return v[1:]
        }
        return make([]string, 0)
    case []int:
        if len(v) > 1 {
            return v[1:]
        }
        return make([]int, 0)
    default:
        log.Panicf("unknown slice type %#v", v)
    }

    return make([]interface{}, 0)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так :

```
func SliceShift(slice interface{}) interface{} {
   s := slice.([]string)
   return s[1:]
}

func main() {
   fmt.Println(SliceShift([]string{"a", "b", "c"}))
}
```

[вот рабочий пример](https://play.golang.org/p/LsfaI6JzQqI)

если в функцию нужно передавать разные типы (можно сделать в SliceShift 2й аргумент который будет указывать тип) и внутри функции проверку к какому типу преобразовать. Вот пример:

```
func SliceShift(slice interface{}, tp int) interface{} {
    switch (tp) {
        case 0: return slice.([]string)[1:]
        case 1: return slice.([]uint64)[1:]
        case 2: return slice.([]byte)[1:]
        case 3: return slice.([]float32)[1:]
    }
    return struct{}{}
}

func main() {
   fmt.Println(SliceShift([]byte("test"), 2))
   fmt.Println(SliceShift([]string{"a", "b", "c"}, 0))
}
```

только учтите что передав не корректные типы будет паника.